# Model Design As Database Table Or Multi-Dimensional List?

Tags: c#, linq, class, data-structures

I'm working with a group of data (the Bible), with recurring fields (Book, Chapter, etc...), and am trying to decide on how to structure it.

Here is an example of the two designs that I'm looking at.  Is one more useful/appropriate/beneficial than the other?

Table Design:

```
class Bible
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public int Chapter { get; set; }
    public int Verse { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, there is a lot of wasted memory in the table design (because of repeated data).  The version will be the same for every entry, the book will be repeated for most entries, the chapter will be repeated for less entries.  Only the verse and text would be unique, to each record.  On the other hand, that's how databases have worked forever (unless you're going the relational route).  It's super-easy to grab data.

List Design:

```
class Verse
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
class Chapter
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<Verse> Verses { get; set; }
}
class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
class Bible
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

This is much more concise, from a memory stand-point, but then you have `foreach` for everything that you need to find.  I'm not sure if LINQ works as well, with multi-dimensionality (maybe it's great, but I've only used it on flat data).

What do you guys think?  Are there times when each is an obviously choice or is one always going to be the default choice?

Comment: You might not get a good answer as this is probably going to be considered opinion-based, but your List design seems the right way to go and Linq is amazingly efficient!

Comment: How you store you data and how you present it are really two different problems.  I'd stickwith the 3rd normal form for storing the data.  It is simple and quick to query using Linq and project the data anyway you need to use it.

Comment: Do some reading on data normalization. You'll quickly reject option 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one would be the better choice for all default operations. Your table construct is just that, a flat table. It's missing all database features, like fast lookup with indices.

In the second version, you could find a book and then have all chapters in it. In the table version, whatever you do, you have to transverse your whole data structure.

The table version has redundant data *and* is slower to use. Seems like a win-win for the real data model.

Comment: I'm in the process of learning object-oriented programming and my brain keeps going back to things I know (like databases).  It seemed like the `List<t>` was better, but more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your List Design is to use dictionaries:

```
class Verse
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
class Chapter
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Verse> Verses { get; set; }
}
class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
class Bible
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Book> Books {get; set;}
}
```

Now there's no `foreach` to find a book. Instead, you reference it by name. That is, assuming you have a `Bible` reference and you want the book of Genesis:

```
Book genesis = myBible.Books["Genesis"];
```

That's one possible in-memory organization, but not necessarily "the best." In fact, "the best" depends in large part on how you want to use it. If you'lre always going to be looking things up by Book:Chapter:Verse, then this is very good because the lookups are very fast. With the List organization, you have to do a sequential scan to find a particular Book, then scan its list of Chapters, and finally scan the list of Verses.

But the Dictionary organization isn't so great if you want to present everything in order. You'd need a separate index that holds the order of the Books, Chapters, and Verses.

And that's just the in-memory organization. How you want to persist the information is another question. You could use a normalized database, which would make querying very convenient. Or you could store the hierarchical Dictionary or List organizations in a text file. It really depends on how you're going to use the data. There is no universal "best" solution here.

Comment: I've seen dictionaries used, but not this nested.  The intention is a master/detail UI where a series of chapters is presented, in the master.  The user clicks the chapter reference and the list of verses is presented, in the detail.

Comment: @doublej: the depth of nesting here is very small. In general, if you can represent the hierarchy with nested lists, then you can do it with nested dictionaries as long ad each item has a key field.

Answer (score 0):

- I do not know to which "table design" you refer, but it does not look like a design which has anything to do with databases, per se.
- What you refer to as "list design" actually looks like a NoSQL document schema. You should have a look at MongoDB, which supports such models out of the box and has a very ample .NET driver.
- As for your question, I would definitely go with the second design, over the first. Do Consider that the design you currently have will provide you poor performance, since it requires loading every book, which in itself is costly. Consider "embedding versus referencing" (in relation to document databases) and choose a more suitable model.

  I, for one, would only load a chapter into memory, complete with its verses- since it is the most basic unit of information that you can display on a UI.